# New cassandra bound statement getDate method

Tags: java, spring, date, cassandra

In a somewhat legacy project we were using the version 2 of the cassandra driver in Spring application. 
This version, and in particular the class `BoundStatement` exposed a method [getDate](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/BoundStatement.html#getDate-int-) which returns a java [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). We all know that the old java date api was pretty horrible, but when used with caution it did the job.

Now, because of some necessity we decided to upgrade the cassandra driver to version 3.4. The first thing that was noted was that in this version, the same method [getDate](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.4/com/datastax/driver/core/BoundStatement.html#getDate-int-) now returns a date of type [LocalDate](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.4/com/datastax/driver/core/LocalDate.html) which a class that datastax team implemented to repleace the java's one. The interesting thing about this class is noted in documentation:

> A date with no time components, no time zone, in the ISO 8601
>   calendar. Note that ISO 8601 has a number of differences with the
>   default gregorian calendar used in Java: it uses a proleptic gregorian
>   calendar, meaning that it's gregorian indefinitely back in the past
>   (there is no gregorian change); there is a year 0. This class
>   implements these differences, so that year/month/day fields match
>   exactly the ones in CQL string literals.

So basically, this class truncates the `time` information. This change caused some failures in the unit tests that were based on date comparison and it required some test modification. To me it seems strange actually, but I guess there must be a good reason for such choice by the datastax team. I would be happy to hear the opinion of someone who knows more in regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getDate` from driver 2 was moved to `getTimestamp` in driver 3.0, as explained in the [upgrade guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/upgrade_guide/):

> 15. Getters and setters have been added to “data-container” classes for new CQL types:
>
>     - getByte/setByte for the TINYINT type
>     - getShort/setShort for the SMALLINT type
>     - getTime/setTime for the TIME type
>     - getDate/setDate for the DATE type
>
> The methods for the TIMESTAMP CQL type have been renamed to getTimestamp and setTimestamp.
>
> This affects Row, BoundStatement, TupleValue and UDTValue.

The main justification for this was the addition of a `date` type in Cassandra 3.0.  To prevent future confusion, we moved the existing `getDate` to `getTimestamp` so the get methods match their cql type name.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It was just a bit confusing that the same getter kept working, like it was saying *don't worry everything is working as it should* and I didn't find this particular bit of the guide.